# Using a validation set with LightGBM in ML.Net

Tags: c#, lightgbm, ml.net

I've been working with LightGBM in R, and am trying to transfer my code to C# using ML.net. LightGBM is designed to run with both a validation set and a training set, and I'm trying to get this working. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.trainers.lightgbm.lightgbmregressiontrainer?view=ml-dotnet, it is possible to send both data sets, but no examples are provided and I'm not seeing how. All of the examples of LightGBM use employ the ML.net pipeline concept, e.g.

```
        // Define the trainer.
        var pipeline = mlContext.Regression.Trainers.
            LightGbm(
            labelColumnName: nameof(DataPoint.Label),
            featureColumnName: nameof(DataPoint.Features));

        // Train the model.
        var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.lightgbmextensions.lightgbm?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_LightGbmExtensions_LightGbm_Microsoft_ML_RegressionCatalog_RegressionTrainers_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Nullable_System_Double__System_Int32_

I've tried using pipeline.Fit(trainingData,validData), as the first link seems to suggest, but that doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by it doesn't work? Using the method that takes in two IDataViews is the way you'd want to go about it. Basically, once you've loaded your data, you can use the [TrainTestSplit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.dataoperationscatalog.traintestsplit?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_DataOperationsCatalog_TrainTestSplit_Microsoft_ML_IDataView_System_Double_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int32__) transform to split your data. Then, pass each of the IDataViews produced into the [LightGBM Fit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.trainers.lightgbm.lightgbmregressiontrainer.fit?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_Trainers_LightGbm_LightGbmRegressionTrainer_Fit_Microsoft_ML_IDataView_Microsoft_ML_IDataView_) method.

If you get errors, I would suggest raising an issue on the [dotnet/machinelearning](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning) repo.